# How to set the DEFAULT maven Java Version

Tags: maven

I am tired of editing pom.xml for every new project & adding:
`<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>`
`<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>`
The Default - 1.5 - is unsupported & was last publicly updated 8 years ago.
So where is the option to automatically generate the above into pom.xml?
I use Eclipse as IDE.
I've seen suggestions that this can be achieved by changing settings.xml.
I have not had any success there, so if you're posting a solution, please post a tried a tested example in its entirety.
Also, please remember, my objective is to get the above 2 lines generated into pom.xml when creating a new project, not just to change the default compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `<profiles>` of your `settings.xml` add

```
<profile>
    <id>java8</id>
    <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

To check it is applied properly, go to your project and run `mvn help:effective-pom` command! You should see it in the displayed pom!

Comment: Excellent!  
Effing brilliant!  
Thank you.  
(the Effective POM Tab in the Eclipse POM Editor shows it too)

Comment: Is there a way to get it generated into the _actual_ POM?

Comment: Glad to help, consider accepting the answer :) As to adding it to actual POM there are 2 things I can think of: 1) create an artifact with a template containing those properties  or  2) use external script / template / IDE feature / ... that would generate the POM for you. Also, from your comment I understand you are using Eclipse. There is "Templates" in the Maven configuration in Eclipse which you can use to easy add those. Also consider aksing plugin authors to add an option to generate those by default.